# How to add a PageSize dropdown in pagersetting in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to get the gridview page size from the drop down from the pagersettings

```
  <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast"  PageButtonCount="4" FirstPageText="First"
                        LastPageText="Last" Position="TopAndBottom" />
```

is it possible to do it, or should I go with a dropdown outside the gridview.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridView_pager.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra `DropDownList` that upon `SelectedIndexChanged` it will set your Pager size using the `PageSize` property. Don't forget to re-bind your datasource afterwards.